# Como evitar acesso ao banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

O mundo perfeito seria que nenhum usuário (funcionários da empresa) tivesse acesso ao banco de produção e esse é o meu objetivo, só que não sei quais os passos pra chegar até esse ponto.

Hoje os devs tem uma "cópia" do banco de produção, isso hoje já é um problema, mas além dos devs o time de OPS precisam dos dados de produção pra gerar métricas dos vendedores.

Já pensei em talvez criar uma interface entre o banco de dados e as pessoas que acessam essas informações, mas não sei se essa é uma solução viável e que talvez houvesse outros métodos ou ferramentas para fazer isso.

Quais práticas são utilizadas para proteger os dados do banco de dados, mas mesmo assim diversos setores possam ler os dados para gerar suas próprias métricas?

Comment: Depende do que quer. Esta pergunta falta detalhes, contexto.

Comment: Vou complementar @Maniero

Comment: @KaduAmaral se o foco é segurança talvez [possa partir daqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/learn/modules/data-warehouse-security/index), mas há outras ferramentas também.

Comment: Excelente, vou estudar essa, parece se encaixar perfeitamente em minha arquitetura. Se puder dar exemplo das outras ferramentas, pois não conheço nenhuma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quais os melhores meios de protejer os dados do banco de dados, sendo que várias pessoas tem acesso ao banco, porém nem todas devem poder ver todos os dados (tabelas ou campos específicos).

Em um mundo perfeito, o banco de produção não deve ser acessado diretamente, somente pela aplicação.
Desenvolvedores devem possuir uma réplica do banco, com dados que não necessariamente precisam refletir o de produção.

Como nem tudo é perfeito, a forma mais fácil de controlar o que acontece em um banco, é criar usuários separados para cada pessoa, cada um com suas permissões especificas.

> E mesmo as pessoas que tem acesso a tudo, em um determinado momento pode perde-los.

Preferencialmente para acesso direto ao banco recomendo que os usuários tenham somente permissões de leitura.

#### Update

> Já pensei em talvez criar uma interface entre o banco de dados e as pessoas que acessam essas informações, mas não sei se essa é uma solução viável e que talvez houvesse outros métodos ou ferramentas para fazer isso. (esse é o motivo da pergunta)

Esse é o caminho, talvez não uma interface, mas um serviço de Data Warehouse, onde os dados já estariam consolidados e não seria necessário o acesso direto pelo time de Ops ao banco.

> O problema com as cópias, é que se um dev for desligado, ali contém dados sensíveis que ele possa ter feito backup em alguma conta pessoal e acabar colocando a empresa em cheque.

Neste caso em especifico você deveria estar usando seeds com dados não oriundos do banco de produção. E para já aproveitar o embalo, utilizar alguma forma de migration.

Comment: Olá Marlon, bem vindo a comunidade. Atualizei a pergunta, se puder por favor, complementar sua resposta agradeço.

Comment: Obrigado @KaduAmaral. Pode me dizer que tipo de problemas está enfrentando com as cópias dos bancos para os devs? Assim fica um pouco mais fácil para eu complementar a resposta.

Comment: O problema com as cópias, é que se um dev for desligado, ali contém dados sensíveis que ele possa ter feito backup em alguma conta pessoal e acabar colocando a empresa em cheque.

Comment: @KaduAmaral complementei a resposta, veja se responde as sua dúvidas

Comment: Marlon eu estive vendo a respeito de Data Warehouse, e parece ser o que eu preciso. Sobre o migration, já temos e vou tentar implementar uma solução de dados fakes para os bancos de desenvolvimento. Valeu!